Python Selenium Actions Chains work but stop my program in Firefox
I sometimes use ActionsChains with any problems, today he work but stop my program do you know why?
    scrolling_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#scrolling_bar")
    start = scrolling_bar.location
    ActionChains(driver)\
        .drag_and_drop_by_offset(scrolling_bar, start['x'], start['y'] - 1000)\
        .perform()
    print('This message never be said')
    ActionChains(driver).reset_actions()

The actions is been execute but stop my program

"today it don't work"  so yesterday, executing the same exact code it worked? Then there must have been an update overnight that broke your code compatibility with Firefox. That's the only explanation for code that works one day and the next day don't.

No cause the program work but he shut down

Use an explicit wait to ensure the element is visible before interacting with it.
Try click_and_hold, move_by_offset, and release instead of drag_and_drop_by_offset.
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('YOUR_URL_HERE')

scrolling_bar = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#scrolling_bar"))
)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click_and_hold(scrolling_bar).move_by_offset(0, -1000).release().perform()

print('Drag and drop performed')

driver.quit()


but how could that work one day and stop working the next day? Even if this solves the problem it doesn't explain why the code stopped working at all.

It can be execution IDE problem so try to reinstall it. OR try to clean the cache.
